# json processing in .sh files

Tags: bash, jenkins

```
[
 {
 "id": "1636ea48-28b7-783a-48dd-5e041f10d9e6",
 "name": "Test_Component1",
 "desiredVersions": [],
 "children": false
 },
 {
 "id": "1636f939-136f-4609-ab93-238b1af193fe",
 "name": "Test_Component2",
 "desiredVersions": [],
 "children": false
 }
]
```

I am writing command in Execute Shell window in Jenkins. I have this json in a variable. I want to extract both Id values so further processing in next set of command can be done.

Comment: Try http://blog.librato.com/posts/jq-json

Answer (score 2):

Using `jq`:

```
$ echo "$var" | jq '.[].id'
"1636ea48-28b7-783a-48dd-5e041f10d9e6"
"1636f939-136f-4609-ab93-238b1af193fe"
```

Answer (score -1):

is it a string? If so, you can use a regexp expression to extract the ID´s values. Like:

```
(\"id\"\:\W)\"(.+)(\"\,)
```

Comment: Nothing in the question asks about using the JSON as a payload for an HTTP request.